# "He told that he was hiring 20 additional policemen"

Tags: sentence-construction

Is it grammatically wrong to say these?

> He told that he was hiring 20 additional policemen
>
> The major told that big cities were experiencing the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual basic pattern is *tell someone*. We can add another object to the verb, if we want, and use *tell someone something*:

- Tell Bob.
- Tell Bob (that) we need to leave.

We don't usually use *tell something* without saying which person we were telling.

- *tell (that) we need to leave.  (wrong)

The pattern is the other way round with *say*. The basic pattern is *say something*. If we really want to add a person, we can say *say something to someone*, or *say to somebody something*. Notice that we need *to* if we include the  person we are saying it to.

- He says (that) we need to leave.
- He said (that) he was leaving to me.
- He said to me (that) he was leaving

But we can't *say someone*.

- He already said me. (wrong)

**The original example sentences**

The  examples in the question are both ungrammatical. They use *tell* but they do not explain which person was being told. To make them grammatical, we can either include the person who was spoken to:

> He told **me** that he was hiring 20 additional policemen
>
> The major told **the government** that big cities were experiencing the same problem.

... or we can use the verb *say* instead:

> He said that he was hiring 20 additional policemen
>
> The major said that big cities were experiencing the same problem.

So, the patterns to remember are:

- tell people
- say things

EDIT: As StoneyB says below, there are a small number of 'things' that we can tell. For example we can tell: stories, jokes, lies, the truth - and other words that mean similar things to these. There are also different senses of the verb *tell*. Of of these for example is to 'detect' something. This has a different grammar.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I dont know how can I tell YOU thank you :) wow I have been learning English for a long time and I am kinda stunned how can I missed that..you enlighted me :) thank you

Comment: @Murat You're welcome. Glad it was helpful! :)

Comment: +1 Perzackly - but there are a few 'things' you can tell without an IO: stories, tales, a lie, the truth, and (in slightly different senses) the difference or a specific number.

Comment: @Araucaria 'While one with moderate haste might tell a hundred'. In the sense 'count', actually, you can tell other objects - sheep, children, parsnips ...

Comment: @Murat This was an excellent explanation, I am a native English speaker and I've never had the difference explained to me so clearly.  It's difficult to think about one's own language so clearly.

Comment: And of course a child can "tell on" another child when they have done something wrong.